# I'm getting error like "No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types" in androidstudio

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradlew

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/pinalsevwala/Downloads/flutter3.3.9/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 920
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
> > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [/Users/pinalsevwala/Desktop/Uniqual Project/maintenance-sos-flutter-app/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug]

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 640ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried changing jdk version to lower and higher versions and change distributionUrl and tools version in build.gradle.